# Unity UI Toolkit - Background image

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I was learning the new UI toolkit. I'm trying to add an image to a visual element.
I added an image and saved it. After reopening it, nothing appeared like I didn't add anything.
What can it be about?

[SS of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aytqe.png)

Comment: If your `VisualElement` does not have any content, it will not size itself to the image. You will need to specify `height` / `width` properties

Answer (score 0):

same here, I could overcome the problem by adding the bg image via an txt editor program.

such as

style="width: 60px; height: 60px; padding-right: 10px; background-image: url('project://database/Assets/Images/xxx.png');"

I have no idea why they didn't fix such an obvious issue yet.